# generate png24 asset with a transparent background

Tags: png, photoshop

I am using `file->generate->image assets` command in `photoshop cc` to generate a png file out of a layer.

I have tried `myfile.png8, myfile2.png24, myfile3.png32, myfile4.png`.
then I noticed that only the `*.png24` file doesn't have a transparent background, while all the other files do.

why is it and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Babyy: while editing to improve the clarity of a post is appreciated, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) should not be used for emphasis. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/2074608 for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check the attached image. Did you uncheck the body background layer? If not then try it and find other layers which is covering the full background. Then press ctrl+alt+shift+s to save the image for web where you will find png24 along with other format. Also confirm that you check the transparency button before saving. Hope it will work for you. Please confirm it worked.